# Which rxjs operator to use?

Tags: rxjs

I have an object:

```
let settings = {
    user: {},
    page: {}
}
```

And there are two requests:

```
getUserSettings(): Observer<UserSettings> {
    return http.get();
}

getPageSettings(): Observer<PageSettings> {
    return http.get();
}
```

I need to call them both independent, result of one has no effect to result another but as result get fullfill object `settings`.

Comment: You've tagged multiple versions of RxJS. Assuming `6.x`, [`forkJoin`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin) is what you probably want. Both requests must complete before the combined observable completes.

Comment: What if one of observers fails? ForkJoin works for others?

Comment: forkJoin is await all observers?

Comment: Please refer to the documentation page I linked for [`forkJoin`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin). _"forkJoin will wait for all passed observables to complete..."_ + _"If any input observable errors at some point, forkJoin will error as well and all other observables will be immediately unsubscribed."_

Comment: please elaborate more with specific version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **[forkjoin](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin)** to do that. This function will accept array of observables.

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

forkjoin([getUserSettings(), getPageSettings()])
   .pipe(map(res) => {user: res[0], page: res[1}) // remove this if you don't need the exact setting object as final result
   .subscribe((res) => {
     // settings object
   });
```